# Show that matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Let
$A=\begin{pmatrix} d_1 & e_2 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0\\ e_2 & d_2 & e_3 & \ldots & 0 &0\\ 0 & e_3 &d_3 & e_4 &\ldots &0 \\ \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots &e_n\\ 0 & \ldots &\ldots & 0 & e_n & d_n\end{pmatrix}$.

The following are true:

$d_i > 0 $ for $1 \leq i \leq n$

$d_1 > \left|e_2\right|$

$d_i > \left|e_i\right| + \left|e_{i+1}\right|$ for $2 \leq i \leq n-1$

$d_n > \left|e_n\right|$

Show that the matrix A is positive definite.

Firstly, I can show that A has strict diagonal dominance and therefore is invertible. I have found some theorems that use invertibility to prove positive definite but none suited my case I think.

I have also found the Sylvester's criterion which states that if all principal minors of A are nonnegative then A is positive definite. Well, the first two principal minors are indeed nonnegative, but after that I can't prove it.

Which should my approach be?

Comment: **[Note]** : A matrix with positive determinant doesn't necessarily mean that the matrix is positive definitie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $x=(x_1,\cdots, x_n).$ We get $$xAx^T=\sum_{i=1}^n d_ix_i^2+2\sum_{i=2}^ne_ix_{i-1}x_i.$$

Now we use the inequality $2 ab\ge -a^2-b^2 $ to arrive at

$$xAx^T\ge\sum_{i=1}^n d_ix_i^2-\sum_{i=2}^ne_ix_{i-1}^2-\sum_{i=2}^n e_ix_i^2.$$ In other words

$$xAx^T\ge (d_1-e_1)x_1^2+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}(d_i-e_i-e_{i+1})x_{i}^2+(d_n-e_n)x_n^2.$$ Finally, we conclude using the hypothesis that $x\ne 0\implies xAx^T>0,$ which shows that $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: At the second row, where you used $2ab \geq -a^2 -b^2$, shouldn't it be $e_i > 0 \forall i$ for what you wrote to be true? I understand that $x_{i-1}x_{i} \geq -\frac{1}{2}(x_{i-1}^2+x_i^2) $ and from this point you essentially multiplied by $e_i$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) implies all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive.